# CSS set image dimensions to percentages of parent div without having set dimensions of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

**Proposition:**

I have a div containing two elements, a link and an image with an underscore which is supposed to go on the bottom of it.

However I can't find a good way of setting the width of the image since the parent div doesn't have a set width, the width of the parent should depend on the length of the a-link text.

Additionally, vertical padding is introduced for some reason.
Lastly, the parent div is supposed to be centred on the page.

**Question:**

How would I make the underscore to be set at a fixed distance below the text, like 5px for example?

And, how would I get the boxes to be the same height with the width depending on the containing link's text lengths?

Here is how it looks:

[image: img]

**Here's my code:**

---

```css
.navMain {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.linkBox {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.linkBox a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.linkBox img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navMain">
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/ordering"> Place order</a>
  </div>
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/invoices"> Invoice overview</a>
    <img src="/static/images/internalnavbardiv/blueFilterLine.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/registerinvoice"> Register invoice</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: top` …

Comment: @CBroe Good to know, been trying everything here!

Comment: You can use grids. `Invoice Overview` will be in the `first row` and the rest can be in the `second row`. If that works, I will show how to do it. Yet I always prefer using `Bootstrap`.

Comment: @Alex I've been messing around with grids not, but am unable to figure out how to give the grid set sizes, so that the image doesn't completely mess up the scale of the cell, Bootstrap?

Comment: Grids resize according to the items inside them unless you restrict them in any way. Do you need the links to be exactly the same as the image you put up; Links not being all in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use gradient to achieve this and no need for img or svg:

```css
.navMain {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.linkBox {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.linkBox a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.decorate {
  background:linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom/100% 1px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="navMain">
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/ordering"> Place order</a>
  </div>
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/invoices" class="decorate"> Invoice overview</a>
  </div>
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/registerinvoice" class="decorate"> Register </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use an image or svg as background:

```css
.navMain {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.linkBox {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.linkBox a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.decorate {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/200/100?image=1040) bottom/80% 2px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="navMain">
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/ordering"> Place order</a>
  </div>
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/invoices" class="decorate"> Invoice overview</a>
  </div>
  <div class="linkBox">
    <a routerLink="/registerinvoice" class="decorate"> Register </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `border-bottom:1px solid;`?

Comment: @Rob in the example I made they are similiar but with gradient we can have a width different from 100%, define many colors, avoid having the issue of box-sizing:border box, have it behind the text if needed, etc :)

Comment: Good response and voted useful. However, I'd still like to be able to handle it with an image for future situations, and understand where the padding comes from. Also I'd like to be able to center the decoration and use a width that's say 80% of the text width.

Comment: @MarcusGrass it's easy, simply replace the gradient with an image or svg ;) check the update